# How to undefine symbol for a C# project

Tags: c#, build, constants, pragma

I have a C# project defining a symbol named WIN:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);WIN</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This constant is used in an `#if` preprocessor directive to conditionally perform some actions, namely, to import some libraries:

```
#if WIN
        const string MyExternalLibrary = @"./lib/Win/MyExternalLibrary.dll";
#else
        const string MyExternalLibrary = @"./lib/Linux/MyExternalLibrary.so";
#endif

[...]

  [DllImport(MyExternalLibrary )]
  public static extern IntPtr MyFunction();
```

I'd like the WIN constant to be defined, by default, so that the project can be built on windows machines.

At publish time, however, I'd like it to be undefined, to fall in the `#else` block.

Is there a way to tell `dotnet build` to undefine a symbol (that is, the opposite of `dotnet build`'s `-p` switch)?

Comment: It would be easier to selectively define `NON_WIN` when you want to build for something other than Windows. Then you can use `-p`.

Comment: It depends on what "at publish time" means and how you are publishing. There is also `#undef` available, but almost certainly "the dotnet way" is to use PropertyGroup / build settings.

Comment: Not a solution to the question, but to the problem: define a new variable; in its definition, read its value as env var; add and use it:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TARGET_OS Condition=" '$(TARGET_OS)'==''" >WIN</TARGET_OS>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);$(TARGET_OS)</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Builds will use the specified TARGET_OS value (es: `dotnet publish -c Release --nologo -p:TARGET_OS=LINUX`) or the default WIN value